# How to pass object id to angular material dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Today, I met a problem with passing object(customer) id to angular modal. In the beginning, I was passing customer id to another component like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/customers/single', this.customer.id]"></a>
```

and after this, I was redirecting to another component with customer details. Everything that's I want to archive is passed id to modal component and print customer details in this particular modal without redirecting to another component.

customer details:

```
export interface CustomerDetails {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string,
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  status: string;
  username: string;
}
```

customer-single.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {CustomerService} from "../shared/customer.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {CustomerDetails} from "../model/customer-details";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-single',
  templateUrl: './customer-single.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-single.component.css']
})
export class CustomerSingleComponent implements OnInit {

  customer$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;
  customerDetails$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;
  customer: CustomerDetails;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.customer$ = this.customerService.getOne(id);
  }

  onPreDetailsCustomer() {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.customerDetails$ = this.customerService.getOne(id);
  }

}
```

customer-list.component.html

```
<div>
  <table class="table" style="width: 90%">
    <thead class="table">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">No.</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Surname</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Phone number</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Email</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">NIP</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let customer of ( customers$ | async ); let i = index">
      <td scope="row">{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.surname}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.phoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.nip}}</td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/customers/modify', customer.id]">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Modify</button>
        </a>
          <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="openDialog(customer.id)">Details</button>
        <a (click)="onRemove(customer.id)">
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Remove</button>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" routerLink="products">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></span>Compose basket
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

customer-list.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomerService} from "../shared/customer.service";
import {Customer} from '../model/customer';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {CustomerDetails} from "../model/customer-details";
import {CustomerDetailsDialog} from "../modal/customer-details/customer-details-dialog";
import {MatDialog} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {

  customers$: Observable<Customer[]>;
  customerDetails$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;


  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customers$ = this.customerService.customersView();
  }

  onRemove(id: number) {
    this.customerService
    .remove(id)
    .subscribe(
      customer => console.log('Customer ' + customer + ' successfully removed'),
      error => console.log('Something went terribly wrong: ' + error.message),
      () => setTimeout(() => this.ngOnInit(), 150)
    );
  }

  onPreDetailsCustomer(id: number) {
    this.customerDetails$ = this.customerService.getOne(id);
  }

  openDialog(customerId: number) {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(CustomerDetailsDialog, {
        data: {
          id: this.customerDetails$
        }
      }
    );

    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });

}
```

Additionally, I created a modal directory for modal components.

customer-details-dialog.ts looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'customer-details-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'customer-details-dialog.html',
})
export class CustomerDetailsDialog {

  customer$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
              private customerService: CustomerService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CustomerDetails) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.customer$ = this.customerService.getOne(id);
  }

}
```

customer-details-dialog.html looks like:

```
<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.name}}
</div>

<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.email}}
</div>

<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.phoneNumber}}
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff in ngIf...
</ng-template>
```

After clicking on the details button I am receiving: 
`Loading stuff in ngIf...` in modal window because particular information about the customer is not loaded and we are trying to load #loading component because we can not receive id from the object.

Moreover, in the console, I am receiving:

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/customer/undefined 400`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The dialog component is not a routed component. It doesn't have access to the activated route, and even then, it's opened from the list, which displays many customers and doesn't have any 'id' parameter. Pass the customer ID to the openDialog() method, and use https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component- to pass this ID to the dialog component.

Comment: @Martin you can send data like this `openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for a response, if I got it right, I suppose to pass id from CustomeSingleComponent to CustomerDetailsDialog, right? What do you mean, that I should pass id to openDialog() method? There is no need to use the id in this method. I'm sorry for the meticulous questions, but I'm not with this technology.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for a response, I found that solution but is there an option to pass an entire object without dividing it to the parts?

Comment: Your list component displays a table. Each row of this table displays a different customer. In each row, you have a button which calls openDialog(). And this method opens a dialog which shows the detail of a customer. So how could this method know **which** customer to display in a modal if you don't pass the customer ID as argument?

Comment: I understand the assumption where we need to know the specific id of the client. According to the example: 
[example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyxlkogvgvbp?file=app%2Fdialog-data-example.ts=app%2Fdialog-data-example.ts)

we should pass the id to the open method but it is puzzling to me how then this id will be extracted by the superior component in order to identify a specific client for us.

Comment: By "superior component", do you mean the component displayed inside the modal dialog? If so, just look at the example, and at the documentation I linked to: it's extracted from the data injected in the component constructor.

Comment: @JBNizet You right. This passing value works out of the box. I thought that I need another ,,trick'' to make it happened. Now after this modification i have a method openDialog() like:


  `openDialog() {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(CustomerDetailsDialog, {
        data: {
          id: this.customerDetails$
        }
      }
    );

    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });

  }
`

How to extract id from this observable?

Comment: Again: pass the id of the customer to display as argument to openDialog() method. In the view: `(click)="openDialog(customer.id)`. In the component: `openDialog(customerId: number)`.

Comment: @JBNizet I applied your tips. Including  `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CustomerDetails` in Dialog component with customerId in openDialog() method. I think that after all the problem is with: 
`
data: {
          id: this.customerDetails$
        }
`.

Anyway, I modified the previous version of the code to clarify it a little. 
Thank you so much for your commitment.

Comment: Don't pass customerDetails$. Pass the customerID that you now have as the argument of your method, and load the details from withing the dialog. Or load the details first in openDialog(), and once you have the details, pass them to the dialog. It seems you're trying random things without undrstanding what you're doing. Passing an argument to a method but not using it in the method makes no sense.

Comment: @JBNizet You right, I am struggling with it and after all, I want to check every possibility to archive the goal. The situation is not improved by the fact that these are my first steps with angular and the syntax is slightly different from the typical Java I deal with every day. `and load the details from withing the dialog` You mean that I suppose to call again method getOne() or something another? Thank you so much for your commitment and patient. Enough for today, fatigue takes over. GN

Comment: It's just like in Java: if a method takes an argument, it should use it. If a method openDialog receives a customer ID and must call another method that displays the customer, either openDialog() gets the customer and calls the other method with the customer as argument, or it passes the customerID to the other method, and this other method will load the customer on its own.

Comment: @JBNizet It's clear, so in this scenario, now I suppose to call method 
`this.customerDetails$ = this.customerService.getOne(customerId);` right?
Honestly, I don't know what does it mean, a method which displays customer, You mean, a method which will load data to our observable declared previously or other staff?

Comment: @JBNizet I finally founded a workaround for this problem. I used the localStorage to keep customerId and after usage, I am removing it. Now it's working perfectly but I suppose to find out why the previous solution was not working. Thanks for your commitment.

Answer (score 1):

Use MatDialogRef template like this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'customer-details-dialog.html',
})
export class CustomerDetailsDialog {

  customer$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;

  constructor(public dialog_ref: MatDialogRef< CustomerDetailsDialog >,
        private router: Router,
        @Inject( MAT_DIALOG_DATA ) public data?: string) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if ( this.data )
          this.customer$ = this.customerService.getOne(this.data);
  }

  static open( dialog: MatDialog, id: string ): Observable< boolean> {
    return dialog.open(CustomerDetailsDialog,
      { data: id, disableClose: true }).afterClose();
  }

}
```

Then just call CustomerDetailsDialog.open from your component and pass dialog and id.